# Grizzly Static Content path below the context webapp

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, grizzly

Just spent a day trying to get Grizzly Static Content working. The following URL from the Grizzly Blog explained alot: [Grizzly STatic Content](http://grizzly-nio.net/2013/08/grizzly-httpserver-spring-jersey-serve-static-content-from-a-folder-and-from-a-jar/)
.

I am trying to mimic Tomcat, in that I would the path to the static content to be below the webapp or the context handle.

```
public class SampleAdminApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public SampleAdminApplication() {
        packages("com.companyname.sample.sampleadmin.server.services");
    }
}

public class SampleGrizzlyWebServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create("http://localhost:9090/Sample/"));

            /*--- Static Content ---*/
            String jarPath = getJarPath(SampleGrizzlyWebServer.class);
            CLStaticHttpHandler clStaticHttpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(
                    new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File(jarPath).toURI().toURL()}),
                    "/", "/lib/", "/js/", "/css/");
            ServerConfiguration sc = httpServer.getServerConfiguration();
            sc.addHttpHandler(clStaticHttpHandler,"/SampleUI");

            /*--- SampleAdmin WebappContext ---*/
            WebappContext SampleAdminContext = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "/" + webapp + "/" + "SampleAdmin");

            /*--- Servlet ---*/
            final ResourceConfig sampleAdminRc = new SampleAdminApplication();
            ServletRegistration sampleAdminRegistration = SampleAdminContext.addServlet("ServletContainer", new ServletContainer(sampleAdminRc));
            sampleAdminRegistration.addMapping("/*");

            /**
             * Deploy Server
             */
            SampleAdminContext.deploy(httpServer);
            /**
             * Start Server
             */
            httpServer.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }           
    }
}
```

The above code works with the following URL's:

```
http://localhost:9090/Sample/SampleAdmin/restmethod
http://localhost:9090/SampleUI/hello.htm
```

However I would like the static pages to be below the webapp path "Sample"
Like:

```
http://localhost:9090/Sample/UI/hello.htm
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if I get any badges for answering my own question :)
I worked for a couple of days, trying to implement a forward from a filter. There are multiple unanswered posts on this forum about jersey forwarding. Not obvious how to forward from a filter. EndRant

My solution was to use the deprecated call to HttpHandlerRegistration.builder() that allowed me to effectively set up a /Sample/UI context.

Now the code behaves like Tomcat where Sample/{SampleAdmin,UI} are the endpoints.

```
   startServer("http://", "localhost", "Sample", "UI", "9090");

   public static void startServer(String protocol, String host, String webapp, String ui, String port) {
        try {
            String BASE_URI = protocol + host + ":" + port + "/" + webapp + "/";

            HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI));

            /*--- Static UI Content ---*/
            if(ui!=null && !ui.equals("")) {
                String jarPath = getJarPath(SampleGrizzlyWebServer.class);
                if (jarPath != null) {
                    CLStaticHttpHandler clStaticHttpHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(
                            new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File(jarPath).toURI().toURL()}),
                            "/", "/lib/", "/js/", "/css/");
                    ServerConfiguration sc = httpServer.getServerConfiguration();
                    sc.addHttpHandler(clStaticHttpHandler, HttpHandlerRegistration.builder().contextPath("/" + webapp + "/" + ui + "").urlPattern("").build());
                }
            }

            /*--- SampleAdmin WebappContext ---*/
            WebappContext SampleAdminContext = new WebappContext("WebappContext", "/" + webapp + "/" + "SampleAdmin");

            /*--- Servlet ---*/
            final ResourceConfig sampleAdminRc = new SampleAdminApplication();
            ServletRegistration sampleAdminRegistration = SampleAdminContext.addServlet("ServletContainer", new ServletContainer(sampleAdminRc));
            sampleAdminRegistration.addMapping("/*");

            /**
             * Deploy Server
             */
            SampleAdminContext.deploy(httpServer);
            httpServer.start();

            System.out.println("Jersey app started with WADL available at:");
            System.out.println(BASE_URI + "SampleAdmin/application.wdl");
            System.out.println("Hit enter to stop it...");
            System.in.read();
            httpServer.shutdown();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
           System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```